# QEMU command line hard disk

Tags: fedora, qemu

I've installed Windows 10 as guest. Everything is OK. But I would like to use my physical hard drive (/dev/sdc) with files. When I start the virtual machine only shows 'Booting from hard disk'.
I use Single GPU passthrough ([this tutorial](https://gitlab.com/YuriAlek/vfio)). How to connect this drive? My primary virtual disk is connedted by executing command `-drive file=windows.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2`.

Answer (score 1):

Without trying, reading your one-liner "-drive file=windows.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2" reads quite a bit less and different than described in the tutorial [https://gitlab.com/YuriAlek/vfio/wikis/Use/#windows][1] you refer to.
If setup, as the tutorial describes, a simple 'windows' in your terminal should start the machine